# cakephp - killed session on 404 Not Found error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

i use cakephp-2.5.4 and when i encounter a 404 error, user session killed & user logout from application.

can someone help?

```
public $components = array (
    'Session'
);
```

Comment: can you tell me more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. core.php

   > Configure::write('Exception.handler','AppErrorHandler::handleException');
2. bootstrap.php

   > App::uses('AppErrorHandler', 'Lib');
3. add AppErrorHandler class in Lib folder with following function

   ```
   public static function handleException(Exception $exception)
   {
       if($exception instanceof MissingControllerException ){
           return false;
       }
       $config = Configure::read('Exception');
       //self::_log($exception, $config);
       $renderer = isset($config['renderer']) ? $config['renderer'] : 'ExceptionRenderer';
       if ($renderer !== 'ExceptionRenderer') {
           list($plugin, $renderer) = pluginSplit($renderer, true);
           App::uses($renderer, $plugin . 'Error');
       }
       try {
           $error = new $renderer($exception);
           $error->render();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue:

Please do try this

```
public $helpers = array('Session', 'Html', 'Form');
public $uses = array('Users','Persons');

    public $components = array('Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                            'fields' => array('username' => 'email_address'),
                            'passwordHasher' => array('className' => 'Md5', 'hashType' => 'md5'),
                        )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'user_masters',
                'action' => 'login',
                'admin' => true,
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'user_masters',
                'action' => 'dashboard',
                'admin' => true,
            ), 'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'user_masters',
                'action' => 'login',
                'admin' => true,
            )), "Cookie", "Session", "Email", 'RequestHandler', 'Security');
```

Let me know if any issue.